# List in C# - passing multiple entries as a single object

Tags: c#

I have a method (C#)

```
public void MethodName(List<Order> Order, int ID)
```

I need to pass this to a main page, in which i know to pass integer value to ID, am not able to pass multiple items in a single list.

The List order should have two number entries, (ie. Order.number1 and Order.number2)

How should i pass a single list as a parameter to this method containing multiple entries of number1 and 2, so that i can loop thro' and find it.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You should include some sample source code to help us understand your problem better.

Comment: Could you try to reformulate "i know to pass integer value to ID, am not able to pass multiple items in a single list". I don't understand what you are trying to say here.
Also, what kind of page are you referring to when saying "main page"? Web page? ASP.NET? ASP.NET MVC? Something else?

Comment: I am using webservice method and am calling that webservice in a console app to test, i am not sure how to pass list items as a parameter to a method.

Comment: While calling this method
public void MethodName(List<Order> Order, int ID) 

I need to pass parameter Order in the form of a list, in turn inside the method the order list will be run thro(for each) and passed its elements to DB queries. ie. Order.num1 and Order.num2 should be available inside the Order list.Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, you have:

```
class Order
{
  public int number1 { get; set; }
  public int number2 { get; set; }
  ...
}

List<Order> orders = new List<Order>
{
  { number1 = 123, number2 = 234 },
  { number1 = 321, number2 = 432 }
};
```

You want to be able to search `orders` to find the one where `number1 == ID || number2 == ID`.  Assuming there is only one Order with the given ID or you are OK using the first one you find you can do:

```
public Order FindOrderById(List<Order> orders, int id)
{
  foreach (Order order in orders)
  {
    if (order.number1 == id || order.number2 == id)
    {
      return order;
    }
  }

  // None found.  Return null, throw exception, etc.
  return null;
}

...

List<Order> orders = new List<Order> { ... };
Order foundOrder = FindOrderById(orders, 123);
if (foundOrder == null)
{
  //Not found
}
else
{
  //Found
}
```

You can also use LINQ to shorten this dramatically.  I have included some variations.

```
List<Order> orders = new List<Order> { ... };
int id = 123;

// Throw exception if exactly one order was not found (none or more than one)
Order foundOrder = orders.Single(o => o.number1 == id || o.number2 == id);

// Return null if exactly one order was not found
Order foundOrder = orders.SingleOrDefault(o => o.number1 == id || o.number2 == id);

// Return all orders that matched
IEnumerable<Order> foundOrders = orders.Where(o => o.number1 == id || o.number2 == id);
```

Comment: Single & SingleOrDefault accept predicates.  You can eliminate the Where in those two.

Comment: @Marc: Interesting, hadn't noticed that before.  LINQ is so succinct.

Comment: Ok, so I just looked at some code I had written and I did use it that way.  I guess I hadn't really processed that difference in my head.

Comment: Including the Where method can help define the expression more clearly; either way does the job. Just depends on how much intent you feel you need stated in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class that implements the IList interface. Such as list.

You could do something like:

```
List<Order> myOrders = new List<Order>();
```

Then pass this in to the method.

Where Order is the order object that you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a list from your method (if I'm understanding you correctly)

Edited now that I think I understand better

```
public void MethodName(List<item> order, int ID) {
foreach(Order O in Order)
  {
   RunQuery(O.num1, O.num2);
  }
}
```

Without some knowledge of how your database is set up it's tough to write the query code; I leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks, am not trying to return a list , am trying to pass parameter as a list with multiple entries to a single list so that i can loop thro and populate.

Comment: It should be `List<Order> ... Order O in order` or `List<item> order ... item O in order`.  Neither follow naming conventions, but at least it should compile.  :)